# Application say I'm not member of site

Tags: bug, android-app

Application declined me from voting and participating in site. It claims I'm not a member although I can vote on the web and it properly display my votes.

> [image]

It also incorrectly displays one site twice.

> [image]

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: OnePlus
- Device Model: A0001

  - OS Version: 6.0.1 (2b5f277d1c)

Comment: Probably to do with the switch to HTTPS... does editing the list fix it?

Comment: Restart fixes the list but still can't participate in site.

Comment: Try logging out and back in, pretty sure I remember seeing that the list of sites is refreshed from the API on login

Comment: Your [Network Profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/1477560/janisz?tab=accounts) shows you aren't part of the Science Fiction & Fantasy site.  Are you sure you really are?  Odder still is that your [reputation tab](http://stackexchange.com/users/1477560/janisz?tab=reputation) shows you have reputation for that site...?

Comment: @Cai Logout/Login solved my problem.  I think not all sites are listed, this could be configured.

Comment: @TimmyJim That might be (is, by my investigating) a Hidden Community, which (currently) does not hide _everything_ on the network profile that relates to the hidden sites. This is further proven by following a link to Janisz's sci-fi profile and seeing it does not list a link to the network profile- Hidden communities do this.