# Android App saying I have not joined a community, even though I have

Tags: bug, android-app

So I have been using the mobile app for a while now, with no errors at all. Today I opened the application up as usual and started browsing the Ask Different (Apple) community. When I tried to downvote/upvote/comment, it said

> You are not part of this community, would you like to join it?

I clicked yes, because it wouldn't let me do anything else. Even after clicking yes, it would not let me upvote, and soon crashed.

When I reopened the app, the same thing occurred. I decided to logout, and log back in, but had no success. Finally, I decided to reinstall the app, but once again had no luck.

I am on the Latest Android (7.1.2) and am on a Google Pixel.

Not sure if it's my issue, because the new software updates rolled out today, or if it is a general bug.

Comment: Duplicate ? [Application say I'm not member of site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/294715/307988)

Comment: @Cai I think so. It can't be just a coincidence that these reports started coming. Something probably broke in the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I too just had the same issue.

The solution I found was to clear the app data and cache.

- Go to Settings > Apps > Stack Exchange > Storage
- Click <kbd>CLEAR DATA</kbd>
- Click <kbd>CLEAR CACHE</kbd>
- Open the app and login again.